# Connection loss

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

hint:
Find last word.

```
bd be cd fh de HE  
fe lh pt mt bo*  
LE mk    LA*  
pk ms PE*  
ve mt  
wd       RG*  

* Changing things leads to the desired outcome.
```

The solution will surface, but what are we using for that?

> This is a 2 stage problem

> Every element contains multiple clues

> Counting may (also) help determining stage 2.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

I've got a possible starting point, it's bit tenuous but might be enough to point somebody else in the right direction. Or it might be a total red herring.

It looks like:

> Every column can be made into a set of valid words by inserting a two-letter word in the middle.

Thus:

> in: bind, fine, LinE, pink, vine, wind
>  as: base, lash, mask, mass, mast
>  or: cord, port, blank, PorE*
>  is: fish, mist, LisA*, blank, blank, RisG*

Obviously, this doesn't always work. But:

> The invalid words are the ones that have the footnote about changing things.

So presumably:

> The letters that need to be changed, and the random capital letters, form the final answer.

The title may be a clue in that:

> Small connecting words have been lost from each of the words.

Also:

> There's presumably some other connection between the filler words we need to add, which lets us complete the last two columns. As otherwise there's too many options. And there must be a reason why RG* is in column 4 instead of 2.

Comment: You found 2 hints, and there is a 3rd one to confirm your idea. Don't presume too much though. There are 3 hints to help finding the next step (and 2 to confirm the final answer )

Comment: The specific wording of the non-spoilered "hint" seems to confirm the idea - each word of that line can be associated with one of the first 3 columns.

Comment: For the * words (rot13) : gur hccre pnfr jbeqf orpbzr yvar, ebcr, fnvy, evtf - nyy obngvat grezf, naq ob pbhyq or obng (punatrq sebz ongb), tvivat qr nf qngr.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE:

- I am answering my own question. If you still want to solve it, stop reading if you got enough hints.

Solving this old puzzle:

First impression: This does not look promising:

- Little information
- The 'hint' is in bad English.
- 3 spoiler areas apparently have not been enough to solve it.

But let's try anyway.

The title suggests the theme, apparently, we have to create (or destroy?) connections somehow.

The hint is about the last word; so, I am going to ignore that for now.

But wait. That hint is weird, maybe for a reason. What can we say about the format?

- all three words 4 letter words
- adding "hint" seems superfluous for the message, but it is also a 4-letter word
- 2 words end with t, and two with d (but not in a logical order I can see)
- "hint" and "find" share the middle two letters

Now I have to admit I was a bit stuck. So, I continued with the body.

The body has a lot of 2 letter words.

- With a special format: triangular
- With a remark that talks about changing thing. I will ignore the words with a star for now. (They probably have to be changed in a still unknown way)
- there are 21 words. 16 lowercase, 5 uppercase
- If the remark has a less obvious meaning, it is about "outcome", so it might mean something at the end, but I will ignore that for now.

Trying to make sense out the first row did not bring anything.

Trying the first column might be more promising anyway (all lowercase, uppercase might mean something special). And I found something:

To be honest, I am not sure how I got it, maybe the 4 letter words of the 'hint' were on my mind, but:
All words can be made into 4 letter words by adding "in" between the letters.

Now a lot makes sense.

- The middle letters can be described as lost connecting letters
- The 4-letter outcome coincides with the words of the 'hint'
- And note: Hint and find also where on separate lines for no apparent reason - but they also have "in" as middle letters and are 'first column' words due to the format

The second column word is last, let's check "as". Indeed, we get good words again:

```
bind base
fine lash
LINE mask
pink mass
vine mast
wind
```

Perfect. Now we can continue with "or" and the 4th seems to be "is".

The lasts columns still have a lot of option, esp. since the starred words have something special. RISG is not a word (but is not only starred, but also outside the triangle), and LISA only a name.
However, I noticed something:

That all two letter middles are words on their own. This might be coincidence, but then de could be date and HE could be HIDE? This leads to:

```
bind base cord fish  date(?) HIDE(?)
fine lash port mist  bato->?
LINE mask      LISA->?
pink mass pore->?
vine mast      
wind           RIGS->?
```

Now I am stuck again. The (body of) the puzzle seems almost solved, "but the solution will surface" seems meaningless, so the question is still unanswerable.
I do see many nautical words though; surface may be connected to water surface/see. Let's keep that in mind.

Recap

- The 'hint' -> we used the format; but "Find last word" definitely seems a hint as a sentence
- the *remark -> taken into account, but the awkward formulation may suggest a second meaning
- The title -> we used that
- Considering the (assumed) double meanings, and that the title ideally is appropriate to the entire puzzle: connection, loss or connection loss as a whole will probably apply to a next phase
- The bottom question -> unused though surface may refer to a water surface
- Apart from the this we now have 21 mostly decoded 4 letter words (16 lowercase, 5 uppercase) RISG(?) is the most special, due to its position, and not being a word

Ignoring references to the end, i.e. "desired outcome" and "will surface" in the actual question:

- Find last word
- Connection (and/or) loss
- 16 lower and 5 upper case words
  What kind of puzzle does this hint at?

There are lots of puzzles with connection theme, and loss does not seem useful on its own (though it might refer to loss at sea??)

But 16(+5) words; find a last word is exactly what a

> connect wall is about! Some themes in the 16 lower case words:

```
rope-like: 
bind, vine, cord -> LINE?
hidden:
mask, mist -> HIDE?
nautical:
port, fish, mast, wind?
```

And some thinking on the other words:

```
bato-> anagram of boat (fits nautical: category)
fine    a fine line?
date(?) dateline?
pink
mass
lash
base   baseline?
```

If the anagram theory is correct

```
PORE -> anagram of rope
LISA -> anagram of sail
RISG -> anagram of gris, rigs (rigs has connection with rope and sail)
```

This leads to  an improved? grouping

```
bind vine cord lash? -> ROPE
port mast boat wind? fish? -> SAIL
date base fine fish? -> LINE
mask mist       ->HIDE
```

*lash -> whips are ropelike
*pink -> pink + sail + wikipedia: a sailing ship with a very narrow stern (so fish goes to fishline)
*mass -> hiding in the masses?  seems ok

So we have to move 1 word to the hide category. Doubtful but not impossible: wind (hide in/for a storm) and port (hide in a harbor (for a storm/to not get enlisted), possible hide in port the drink)

Sadly this is unclear (but I forgive the author (yep, that is me) ; using only 4 letter words is very restricting

This leads to the final grouping

```
bind vine cord lash -> ROPE
port mast boat pink -> SAIL
date base fine fish -> LINE
mask mist mass wind -> HIDE
-> RIGS
```

Now hide seems out of place but:
RIGS has meanings apart from 'rigging on a sailing vessel' and we have that text "Changing things leads to the desired outcome" which hints to such a meaning (rigging e.g. an election, an action that you want to keep hidden)

The final question:
The solution will surface, but what are we using for that?

So 'the last word' is rigs; and 'solution will surface'.
Esp. since earlier me considered that surface being water, we get to yet another use of rigs: an oil platform at sea will bring a solution (oil) to the surface.
And what do we do with the solution produced by an oil rig? Move around! To keep to the theme, my final answer will go one step further: We use oil to move around...

> To connect to other people